# C# method in view [ aspnet mvc ]

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a view in my asp.net mvc app, this view need a condition for display (or not) some information.

Unfortunately my condition need to get an object from the session and check several conditions

For example

```
<body>
<sometag>
<....>
<%
var oS = HttpContext.Current.Session["key"];

if(oS.some && oS.other == "other" && oS.Propertie == varInThisPage.Propertie && etc){

if(){

   if(){

       //in any place of universe
       return true;

       }
   }
return false; // for other
}
 %>
</body>
```

The problem is that I have that checks this condition in various part of the view, and do not want to create a method in the model, I feel that assassinate MVC

I thinking create a method in `<% %>` tag, but not working

```
bool MyMethod(){
var oS = HttpContext.Current.Session[InfoWeb.Models.SessionObjects.ConstSession.RT_SESSION];
....
return condition;    
}
```

In `<%` Visual Studio show error `expected {`

When i run, show error in next line with C# code

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Create New", "BG", "CVSD")%> <!-- this work before i create method -->
```

I use asp.net-mvc 2

Comment: You should put that in the controller.

Comment: Controller send only the POCO class to the view, this problem is only for view, in my case. When there is a way to invoke the method from the controller, please let me know, i am java ee dev very unlucky

Comment: Put the logic in the controller and make the result a property of the model.

Comment: This way you are violating technically as well architecturally the principles of MVC. Try using a ViewModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<% %>` blocks can only contain statements.
(the code in the block is placed inside the generated function)

To add fields or methods to the generated class, use `<script runat="server">...</script>`.

Comment: @ataravati: I know (see my comment on the question).  This answer is not wrong. You may be confusing MVC with Razor)

Comment: What I meant by wrong is that it's not a good solution. The code should be inside a Controller, as you rightly said in your comment.

Comment: i agree with ataravatti, it should be on the controller, and call this via ajax or jquery asynchronously. but in any case, for whatever reason, slaks solution will work for you.